# logout function refreshes the page but it's still logged in

Tags: javascript, java, angular, typescript, spring-boot

I am following a course on Udemy, the instructor's side is using Angular 2 and I am trying to build the app using the latest version. The main problem I have, is that the logout function is accessed but because I have to refresh the page to display the login form again, for some reason, after the refresh, I see the login form but then it goes back to the part where I'm logged in.

Logout method on the back-end side:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/loggedOut", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity logout(){
    SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
    return new ResponseEntity("Logout Successfully!", HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Logout function from my login service:

```
logOut() {
const url = 'http://localhost:8181/loggedOut';
const basicHeader = 'Basic ' + localStorage.getItem('credentials');
const headers = new HttpHeaders({
  'x-auth-token' : JSON.stringify(localStorage.getItem('xAuthToken')),
  'Authorization' : basicHeader
});
return this.http.post(url, '', { headers, responseType: 'text'});
```

The button responsible for logging out:

```
logout() {
  this.loginService.logOut().subscribe(
    res => {
      location.reload();
      console.log("Logged out")
    },
    error => {
      console.log(error)
    }
  );
```

Technically, it goes as follow: Logged in -> Login form -> Logged in

Logged in:
[image: Logged in picture]

Log in form:
[image: Logged out]

If I remove the reload method, I can see that the logout method is accessed and I get a 200 from the back-end.

[image: Logged Out]

Network tab before refreshing:

[image: Network tab response]

The server response before refreshing:

[image: Server Response]

Comment: Why are you showing that you are logged in before you even get to the Login Form to keyin your username and password? Also your logout function should clear your credential variables otherwise they remain and you will still be logged in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try clearing out your `localStorage` when logging out:

```js
localStorage.clear();
```

Basically, this removes any trace that the app left when logging in.

Answer (score 0):

**Try This Approach **

```
logout() {
   this.loginService.logOut().subscribe(
    res => {

      if(res) {
        // clear localStorage
        localStorage.clear();
        //navigate to login component
        this.router.navigate(['loginPagePathName']);
        console.log("Logged out")
      }     
    },
    error => console.log(error));
}
```

We don't need to refresh the page
Note :- You can also clear the local storage whenever login component load into the browser simply put localStorage.clear() inside ngOnInit method of loginComponent